# MySQL 5.0 High CPU Usage - performance tuning

Tags: mysql, database, performance, tomcat

Env: Webapp running on tomcat-6 with hibernate-3 as the interface to db.

Since recently, MySQL has been hogging up 100% of CPU time.

I am doing consecutive reads of a large number with little to no writing to DB.

The service was setup with the default my.ini params. Unable to debug where the issue is arising out of.

PS: I was reading about the leap second bug and thought it might be related because though MySQL is running on Win XP 32 bit, the windows OS itself is running on a linux OS as a VM image. Could there be an issue because of the leap second fix not being applied on the underlying linux?

[image: Mysql Process specs 1]
[image: System process specs]

Any pointer is much appreciated

Comment: I would say dba.stackexchange.com would be better.

Comment: do you want me to remove it from here? I've seen a few mysql performance related questions over here and assumed this to be the correct place.

Comment: Check the mysql running queries, using "show processlist". Maybe one or more could benefit from tuning. It may be a locking issue too, innodb uses spinlocks in a couple of place, which uses a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I've most often seen this caused from too much context switching. Take a look at the [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) and [innodb_concurrency_tickets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_concurrency_tickets) parameters.

Innodb_thread_concurrency is 0 by default on some versions, which means unlimited, however, try setting it using MySQL recommendations:

> A recommended value is 2 times the number of CPUs plus the number of
>   disks.

Comment: innodb_thread_concurrency is 8 while innodb_concurrency_tickets is not set. the dubious thing is that until recently, the app and mysql were performing just fine. only since a week and with no changes has this occurred.